# lists of tibble to column in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I want to create a column which is a list of tibbles (of different row number).
The straight forward way fails.
Example:

```
> x <- data.frame('a' = 1:2, 
+                 'b' = list(tibble('c' = 1:4, 'd' = 1:4),
+                            tibble('c' = 1:3, 'd' = 1:3)))
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3
```

I can avoid the error by wrapping it with `I`. However, when I do so, and try to unnest I can't.

```
> x <- data.frame('a' = 1:2, 
+                 'b' = I(list(tibble('c' = 1:4, 'd' = 1:4),
+                            tibble('c' = 1:3, 'd' = 1:3))))
> x %>% unnest(cols = b) 
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a b               
  <int> <I<list>>       
1     1 <tibble [4 x 2]>
2     2 <tibble [3 x 2]>
```

How can I create a column which is a list of tibble, which later I can unnest?

Comment: This is a bug that will be rectified in a future update - see https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/issues/1463 - a workaround at the moment is to `unclass(b)` or `vctrs::vec_proxy(b)` before unnesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to create list columns using `tibble`s instead of `data.frame`s (See e.g. Hadley's note on this [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1)).

You can fix your code by swtiching from `data.frame()` to `tibble()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

x <- tibble(
  'a' = 1:2,
  'b' = list(
    tibble('c' = 1:4, 'd' = 1:4),
    tibble('c' = 1:3, 'd' = 1:3)
  )
)

x
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>       a b               
#>   <int> <list>          
#> 1     1 <tibble [4 × 2]>
#> 2     2 <tibble [3 × 2]>

x %>% tidyr::unnest(b)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>       a     c     d
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     1     2     2
#> 3     1     3     3
#> 4     1     4     4
#> 5     2     1     1
#> 6     2     2     2
#> 7     2     3     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Note that data frame actually **supports** list columns

Comment: You're right. I was misremembering. It's just that base R doesn't make it easy to create them. I'll update my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

you can create the data.frame without list-column first and add the list:

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
x$b <- list(tibble('c' = 1:4, 'd' = 1:4),
            tibble('c' = 1:3, 'd' = 1:3)
           )
```

control:

```
str(x)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ a: int  1 2
# $ b:List of 2
#  ..$ : tibble [4 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  .. ..$ c: int  1 2 3 4
#  .. ..$ d: int  1 2 3 4
#  ..$ : tibble [3 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  .. ..$ c: int  1 2 3
#  .. ..$ d: int  1 2 3
```